# HLSL DirectX: Issue with color generated in PS

Tags: directx, hlsl

The simple HLSL code below generates 3 lines with colors from a table, indexed by SV_VertexID.
It is expected each line with different colors in the vertices and varying colors in the middle.

"option 2" is OK: Get the colors in the VS (lookup table) and send it to PS.

"option 1" is NOT OK: Send the index to PS and get the colors directly in the PS (by lookup table).
In this case each line has the same color (not varying colors).

I do not understand why "option 1" is not working.

This is the shader code:

```
static float2 vertices[6] = {
   float2(-0.95f, -0.95f),
   float2(0.95f, 0.95f),
   float2(-0.95f, 0),
   float2(0.95f, 0),
   float2(-0.95f, 0.95f),
   float2(0.95f, -0.95f)
};

static float3 colors[6] = {
   float3(1,0,1), // purple
   float3(0,0,1), // blue
   float3(0,1,1), // cyan (azul claro)
   float3(0,1,0), // green
   float3(1,1,0), // yellow
   float3(1,0,0) // red
};

struct Output { 
  float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
  float3 color1 : COLOR;
  uint vID : TEXCOORD0; 
};

//----------------------------------------- Vertex Shader
Output VSMain(uint vID : SV_VertexID) {
   Output v1;
   v1.pos = float4(vertices[vID], 0, 1);
   v1.color1 = colors[vID];
   v1.vID = vID;
   return v1;
}

//----------------------------------------- Pixel Shader
float4 PSMain(Output v1) : SV_Target {

   float4 color2 = float4(colors[v1.vID],0); // option 1
   //float4 color2 = float4(v1.color1,0); // option 2

   return color2;
}
```

Comment: What Shader Profile and what do you get as the output from the compiler?

Comment: Shader profile: I tried on both DX12 shader model 6.4 and DX11 shader model 5.0. About Compiler output: Not sure how to answer this.

Comment: I think Option 1 doesn't work because no colour interpolation is possible and the pixel colour is instead a constant value determined by the "provoking vertex" which is the first vertex of each line primitive.

Comment: Got it, thank you. There is no sense in using an interpolated index for the lookup table. Instead, I can create a color based on the interpolated index.

Answer (score 0):

Maico De Blasio gave me a direction so I should answer my own question.

"option 1" should be: Send an interpolated index to PS (v1.vID should be float) and try to get the colors directly from the lookup table, what makes no sense because the "index" is highly fragmented, not integer.

Alternativelly, it is possible to build in the pixel shader a color based on this "index" as shown in the code below:

```
static float2 vertices[6] = {
   float2(-0.95f, -0.95f),
   float2(0.95f, 0.95f),
   float2(-0.95f, 0),
   float2(0.95f, 0),
   float2(-0.95f, 0.95f),
   float2(0.95f, -0.95f)
};

struct Output { 
  float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
  float vID : none; 
};

//----------------------------------------- Vertex Shader
// executed once for each vertex of the element, so this can be 'heavy'.
//
Output VSMain(uint vID : SV_VertexID) {
   Output v1;
   v1.pos = float4(vertices[vID], 0, 1);
   v1.vID = (float)vID;
   return v1;
}

//----------------------------------------- Pixel Shader
// executed once for each pixel of the element, so this should be 'light'.
// for each pixel, v1 is INVENTED (interpolated) between element vertices.
//
float4 PSMain(Output v1) : SV_Target {

   int intPart = (int)v1.vID; 
   float decPart = 1 + intPart - v1.vID;

   switch (intPart)
   {
       case 0: return float4(decPart,0,0,0);
       case 2: return float4(0,decPart,0,0);
       case 4: return float4(0,0,decPart,0);
   }
   return float4(0,0,0,0);
}
```